# Когда слово начинается с у-/у

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Я думаю, оба варианта правильны, хотя я спрашиваю, потому что думаю, что, возможно, – то есть я в этом не уверен – дефис можно использовать вот так, только если мы используем, т. е. имеем в виду, либо окончание, либо суффикс, либо конрень, либо приставку или префиксоид, либо часть сложного слова.

P. S. Это я вопрос викторинный сделал. Я знаю, что *полу-* всегда – за исключением имён собственных и многосложных словосочетаний, конечно, – пишется-таки слитно.

`1.Приставка полу- пишется всегда слитно, за исключением того случая, когда слово, к которому полу- прибавлено, начинается либо с у-, либо с э-, напр.: полукот, полуёжовый, полуброшюра, полулюстра, полудруг, полу-улей, полу-эго, полу-этаж.`

`1.Приставка полу- пишется всегда слитно, за исключением того случая, когда слово, к которому полу- прибавлено, начинается либо с у, либо с э, напр.: полукот, полуёжовый, полуброшюра, полулюстра, полудруг, полу-улей, полу-эго, полу-этаж.`

Comment: *Полуёжовый* — это какой такой?

Comment: Я случайно-таки *ё*, а не *е* поставил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Викторина так викторина.

• Правильно: *полуежовый* (формально), *полуулей, полуэго, полуэтаж.*
В орфографическом словаре: [полуулыбка](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0), полуустав, полуэкипаж, полуэскадрон.

•• Я бы написала так:
Когда слово, к которому *полу-* прибавлено, начинается либо с **у**, либо с **э**...
Или так:
Когда слово, к которому *полу-* прибавлено, начинается либо с У, либо с Э...

**У-** (или **у-**) — так обычно обозначается приставка.

В справочниках и словарях:

> ...если вторая часть сложного слова начинается с гласной буквы или согласной ***л***...
> Но если слово начинается с А, будьте уверены — заимствованное.
> Cлoвapныe cлoвa нa бyквy Э

••• *Полу-* — это не приставка, но первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно (кроме слов с дефисом [*полу-конференц-зал*] и имен собственных [*полу-Африка*]).

*Его **полуулыбка** выглядела торжествующе...* (Даниил Гранин. Зубр).
*...родич пустил на "фатеру" в подвальный сырой **полуэтаж**...* (Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон).
*И **полуэскадрон** красноармейцев при них* (А. И. Солженицын. Эго).

Comment: *Полу-* – это также префиксоид, поэтому мы, например, должны писать *полукошенный луг*, но *свежекошеный луг*.